# What is wrong with my CSV import code in Django?

Tags: django

I have overridden my admin change_list.html

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}

{% block object-tools-items %}

    <li>
        <a href="importcsv/" class="grp-state-focus" class="addlink">Import CSV</a>
    </li>
    {{ block.super }}

{% endblock %}
```

When I click this Import CSV link, I would like to import CSV and save to my model.

App's name Auction. Objects of Auction:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
import csv
from auction.models import AuctionGroup, AuctionHouse, AuctionList

class DataInput(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()


def save(self):
    records = csv.reader(self.cleaned_data["file"])
    for line in records:
        house = AuctionHouse()
        house.house_name = line[0]
        house.auction_type = line[1]
        house.auction_day = line[2]
        house.volume = line[3]
        house.aleado_id = line[4]
        house.aleado_photo_number = line[5]
        house.house_region = line[6]
        house.save()
```

views.py

```
def csv_import(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DataInput(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            success = True
            context = {"form": form, "success": success}
            return render_to_response("auction/importcsv.html", context,
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = DataInput()
        context = {"form": form}
        return render_to_response("auction/importcsv.html", context,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',  
    url(r'/importcsv/$', views.csv_import, name='importcsv'),
)
```

project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^auction/', include('auction.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

importcsv.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action=".">
        {{ form }}
    </form>
</html>
```

But it does not work. Please, help. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `{% url %}` tag in the link code:

```
<a href="{% url 'importcsv' %}" class="grp-state-focus addlink">Import CSV</a>
```

If you want to use single template for multiple models then `change_list.html` has the `cl.opts` context variable which is a `Model._meta` of the current model.

So you can pass the `app_label` and `model_name` to your `importcsv()` view:

```
<a href="{% url 'importcsv' cl.opts.app_label cl.opts.model_name %}"
                             class="grp-state-focus addlink">Import CSV</a>
```

Change your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',  
    url(r'/importcsv/(\w+)/(\w+)/$', views.csv_import, name='importcsv'),
)
```

And the signature of the view function:

```
def csv_import(request, app_label, model_name):
    ...
```

Comment: Thx. It worked. I would like to modify this code and would like to ask a related question. How can I make switch between Models like when I click Import CSV on curtain model it uploads CSV into this model?

Comment: Great! You are always very helpful.